# awk remove rows older X days inside file first days of the month problem

Tags: bash

I have this simple file "lista_file" created every day dynamically:

```
Fri Oct 20 20:47:58 CEST 2023 ANDREA_20231013_000002_10800s+60s_rec-uk-london-03.mp3
Fri Oct 20 20:47:58 CEST 2023 ANDREA_20231014_000002_10800s+60s_rec-uk-london-03.mp3
Fri Oct 20 20:47:58 CEST 2023 ANDREA_20231015_000002_10800s+60s_rec-uk-london-03.mp3
Fri Oct 20 20:47:58 CEST 2023 ANDREA_20231020_090002_10800s+60s_rec-uk-london-03.mp3
Fri Oct 20 20:48:12 CEST 2023 ANDREA_20231124_090002_10800s+60s_rec-uk-london-03.mp3
Fri Oct 20 20:48:12 CEST 2023 ANDREA_20231125_120002_10800s+60s_rec-uk-london-03.mp3
Fri Oct 20 20:48:12 CEST 2023 ANDREA_20231126_150002_10800s+60s_rec-uk-london-03.mp3
Fri Dec 1 13:10:30 CET 2023 ANDREA_20231128_000005_10803s+60s_rec-de-adcontrol-01.mp3
Fri Dec 1 13:10:30 CET 2023 ANDREA_20231129_000005_10803s+60s_rec-de-adcontrol-01.mp3
Fri Dec 1 13:10:30 CET 2023 ANDREA_20231130_000005_10803s+60s_rec-de-adcontrol-01.mp3
Fri Dec 1 13:10:30 CET 2023 ANDREA_20231201_000005_10803s+60s_rec-de-adcontrol-01.mp3
Sat Dec 2 01:10:54 CET 2023 ANDREA_20231201_180000_10800s+60s_rec-de-adcontrol-01.mp3
Sun Dec 3 01:10:28 CET 2023 ANDREA_20231202_210000_10798s+60s_rec-de-adcontrol-01.mp3
```

I use awk command to extract rows older 5 (five) days and work great **but only inside** current month:

`awk -F "_" -v d="$(date +%Y%m%d)" '$2<=(d-5) && /mp3/' lista_file`

For example if today is 20231203 the awk don't extract correct output, I want to calculate always "date today - 5 days" including the previous month, can you help me, please?

Comment: please update the question to show the expected output

Comment: Is there any relevance to some of the dates at the start of your input not matching the date you're comparing on the same line, e.g. the first `Dec` line starts with `Fri Dec 1` but the date field is `20231128` (i.e. Nov 28)?

Comment: You say in the subject that you want to remove lines older than 5 days but then your code attempts to do the opposite. Do you want to print rows older than 5 days or print rows newer than 5 days or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU awk for time functions:

```
$ awk -F'_' '
    BEGIN { d = strftime("%Y%m%d",mktime(strftime("%Y %m %d 12 0 0")) - 432000) }
    $2<=d && /mp3/
' lista_file
Fri Oct 20 20:47:58 CEST 2023 ANDREA_20231013_000002_10800s+60s_rec-uk-london-03.mp3
Fri Oct 20 20:47:58 CEST 2023 ANDREA_20231014_000002_10800s+60s_rec-uk-london-03.mp3
Fri Oct 20 20:47:58 CEST 2023 ANDREA_20231015_000002_10800s+60s_rec-uk-london-03.mp3
Fri Oct 20 20:47:58 CEST 2023 ANDREA_20231020_090002_10800s+60s_rec-uk-london-03.mp3
Fri Oct 20 20:48:12 CEST 2023 ANDREA_20231124_090002_10800s+60s_rec-uk-london-03.mp3
Fri Oct 20 20:48:12 CEST 2023 ANDREA_20231125_120002_10800s+60s_rec-uk-london-03.mp3
Fri Oct 20 20:48:12 CEST 2023 ANDREA_20231126_150002_10800s+60s_rec-uk-london-03.mp3
Fri Dec 1 13:10:30 CET 2023 ANDREA_20231128_000005_10803s+60s_rec-de-adcontrol-01.mp3
```

Obviously change `$2<=d` to `$2>d` if you you wanted to print lines newer than the date instead.

Answer (score 2):

Don't compute the "5 days ago" in awk, which won't take into account the days, but consider that string just a number. Ask `date` to do that computation for you:

```
date -d '5 days ago' +%Y%m%d
```

You will end up with:

```
awk -F "_" -v d="$(date -d '5 days ago' +%Y%m%d)" '$2<=d && /mp3/' lista_file
```

Comment: GNU date only tho...

Comment: Hi Poshi, thank for your support, it works properly! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Ruby to do that for those who do not have GNU date on their system:

```
ruby -r date -ane '
    print if /\.mp3$/ && Date.parse($F[6].split("_")[1])<=(Date.today-5)
' file
```

Prints:

```
Fri Oct 20 20:47:58 CEST 2023 ANDREA_20231013_000002_10800s+60s_rec-uk-london-03.mp3
Fri Oct 20 20:47:58 CEST 2023 ANDREA_20231014_000002_10800s+60s_rec-uk-london-03.mp3
Fri Oct 20 20:47:58 CEST 2023 ANDREA_20231015_000002_10800s+60s_rec-uk-london-03.mp3
Fri Oct 20 20:47:58 CEST 2023 ANDREA_20231020_090002_10800s+60s_rec-uk-london-03.mp3
Fri Oct 20 20:48:12 CEST 2023 ANDREA_20231124_090002_10800s+60s_rec-uk-london-03.mp3
Fri Oct 20 20:48:12 CEST 2023 ANDREA_20231125_120002_10800s+60s_rec-uk-london-03.mp3
Fri Oct 20 20:48:12 CEST 2023 ANDREA_20231126_150002_10800s+60s_rec-uk-london-03.mp3
Fri Dec 1 13:10:30 CET 2023 ANDREA_20231128_000005_10803s+60s_rec-de-adcontrol-01.mp3
```